# presto query error column must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, presto

I have a problem with this query, its logic force me to group by just by date key and number, this error "a.recharge must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause", change entire logic and it's wrong, can you please help me?

```
%jdbc(presto)
select 
        a.date_key,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(a.number)) as dist_number,
        a.recharge,
        b.amount,
        sum(a.recharge)*1.0 / sum(coalesce (NULLIF(b.amount,0),1)) as prct
    

        from( 
        (select 

        date_key,
        number,
        recharge

        

        
from table_1 where (date_key >= 20220101 and date_key <= 20220130)) as a
full outer join 

    (select
        
        date_key,
        number,
        amount
        from table_2 where date_key >= 20220101 and date_key <= 20220130) as b
   
   on a.date_key = b.date_key
   and a.number = b.number 
   
   )
   
   group by a.date_key,
   a.number
   
   order by a.date_key
```

Comment: Can you please add sample data and expected output?

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, I acknowledge that I should put , sum(recharge), sum(amount) over that columns to make the group just by date key.

Comment: Hi @fatane -- could you please add sample data and expected output? And how did you end up solving it?